# How to edit page <title> tag in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using custom search module in joomla 2.5 and I need to add extra text to the title tag on module. But I cant seem to find where the tag is located in Joomla. Does any of you guys know where it is located and how can I override page title ? Thanks

Comment: You can try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731912/how-to-add-extra-text-to-the-title-tag-in-joomla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@George Wilson is close, but the `$this` will only work depending on what context you are in/

Instead you can do something as simple as the following pretty much anywhere (though this should be something set by either the component or a plugin specifically meant to improve page titles globally in some way).

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle('Set your title here');
```

Do note though that if you set this in a module or elsewhere, something else can come along later in the code and override this.

Comment: David is correct that the title may be overwritten depending on where you put this code. You can overcome that issue by using a plugin and putting it at the end of the operating order. This is how RSSEO changes page titles correctly, but that component is probably much more than you need for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The `title` tag should NOT be set by a module - but by the component on the page. Having said that you can do it through:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$this->setTitle( 'This is the title that you wish to place' );
?>
```

Link [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_dynamic_page_title) for more info

Comment: so there is not any possibility to change page title on module ?

Comment: Do you mean the page `<title>` tags or the title of the module. If its the `<title>` tag in the header - the answer is no. As I stated in my answer above - the title of the page is set between the component and the template. Modules are not supposed to be the main feature of the page - and thus there is no native way of setting it in the Joomla! Admin Backend. Only by doing some kind of template override

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php
```

Take a look at that on **LINE 102**. You will be able to control everything... :-)

Comment: You missed `joomla` subdirectory in your path. Path must be `/www/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line:

`JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle('Set your title here');`

after

`$app = JFactory::getApplication();`

in the following file:

`public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php`